# Trying to map a drive to a folder in the user's shared Sharepoint Directory

Tags: command-line, mapped-drive, azure-activedirectory, subst

We are trying to map a drive to a folder that is in the user's shared Sharepoint Directory. This has worked for about half of the user's so far but for some reason the script is not working for other users.

The script we are attempting to use is `subst L: "C:\Users\username\SharePointDirectory\temp"`.  This script is being placed in this startup folder "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp". We are placing the folder there so that the drive is mapped at bootup. Placing this script in that path has worked for about half of the users we have made a script for but there is no difference besides the username in the folder path.

I have received 'path not found' errors when running directly on a user's command line even though I can see the folder that we are trying to run the subst command for is there.

Each user is on an AzureAD joined profile on Windows 10.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please add the actual relevant script commands to the question. For many reasons, the standard cmd way to access stuff in the current user's profile is via environment variable `%USERPROFILE%`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer edited, given that the question contained an error in the example but thats not actually the real case, making me post an answer to a non-existing problem.

What you can try else is the following script:

```
cd /d %userprofile%\SharePointDirectory\temp
subst l: .
pause
```

If you run it, you will be able to see where things go wrong. It should change the folder to the correct one first, and if that folder does not exist for some weird reason, the cd command will fail. If it does change, the subst should map l: to the current directory.

Pause is there so you can see its progress as its running.

Comment: I have been using the user's username so I edited the post to more accurately reflect what I'm trying to do.